# how to use callable functions in kstest?

Tags: python, scipy

```
def Ftrapz(x):
    global a2
    if x<a:
        a2=0
    elif a<=x<=b:
        a2=(0.5*k1*x**2+b1*x)-(0.5*k1*a**2+b1*a)
    else:
        a2=(0.5*k1*b**2+b1*b)-(0.5*k1*a**2+b1*a)
    return a2

trapz_test=stats.kstest(x0,Ftrapz)
```

I want to use stats.kstest to test the array x0 and the distribution function which defined by my own. but there are some wrong in this program, so how to use the callable function exactly? 
it's said:

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is
>   ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: Your question is unclear. We need more context. Please read [ask].

Comment: "Something is wrong in this program", what is it? We can't diagnose an issue if we don't know what it is.

Comment: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Answer (score 0):

The method `kstest` passes a NumPy array as argument to Ftrapz. So, in your if-statement, `x<a` an array of Booleans, which results in the error about ambiguity. The solution is **not** to use `all` or `any`, but to rewrite the function so that it handles arrays. A typical way to do this is with [`numpy.piecewise`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.piecewise.html), which takes a list of ranges and a list of functions to be executed over those ranges (they may be constant). Your function could be expressed as:

```
def Ftrapz(x):
    ranges = [x < a, np.logical_and(a <= x, x <= b), x > b]
    values = [0, lambda x : (0.5*k1*x**2+b1*x)-(0.5*k1*a**2+b1*a), (0.5*k1*b**2+b1*b)-(0.5*k1*a**2+b1*a)]
    return np.piecewise(x, ranges, values)
```

Note that comparison of NumPy arrays can't be nested as conveniently as for scalars: `a <= x <= b` would throw an error. One can avoid the messy `logical_and`   by making the corresponding formula the last one, so that it's executed when other conditions fails:

```
    ranges = [x < a, x > b]
    values = [0, (0.5*k1*b**2+b1*b)-(0.5*k1*a**2+b1*a), lambda x : (0.5*k1*x**2+b1*x)-(0.5*k1*a**2+b1*a)]
```